# Is there a way to determine the power of another character in Fallout 3 (similar to borderlands)?

Tags: fallout-3

I'm still somewhat new to the Fallout universe, and really enjoy Fallout 3.

I also recently started playing Borderlands as well. In borderlands, characters have their level when you hover over them, and quickly lets you know if you should attack or not (if you are a 3 and they are a 10, you should hold out).

Is there something like this in Fallout 3? I know you level up and get stronger/smarter over time, but how do I know if someone is too much for me? When I first started playing this a year or so ago, I would run into someone that was just too powerful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't, as such. (In New Vegas, I believe one of the higher-level perks will tell you.)

However, if you highlight someone with VATS, you can get some indication, as you'll see how much (or how little, natch) damage your current weapon will do to them upon a successful hit. (Note that you'll see primarily what a critical hit would do; divide that roughly by half to see what a normal hit will do.)

Comment: This makes sense. I have been using VATS more when I restarted the game. Now I just need to read up more on it. One question in regards to your answer - do you mean if I see a bunch of low percentages - that means I am really not prepared to take on that enemy?

Comment: @jmlumpkin: That, or you're using the wrong gun. :) Although bear in mind some guns (minigun, gatling laser) are really not VATS-friendly. They often show very little damage, and are much better used as a straight shooter weapon.

Comment: @jmlumpkin: Wrong gun or you're too far. To-hit chance is not determined by enemy level but by your skill, weapon accuracy, target size (and obstructions) and (primarily) distance. It is often smart to allow melee opponents very close then take them down with 2-3 headshots of 95% chance, than to use up all AP at maximum distance then try to fend off without VATS when they approach.